# Changing background opacity preserving the text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to trim down the opacity of my `carousel-caption`, but the text gets the opacity too, any ideas how to overcome this? I'm using bootstrap and would prefer to keep things as simple as possible. Is it possible to achieve this without using something like: `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`?

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
   <h1 class="carousel-caption-header">Heading for random text</h1>
   <p class="carousel-caption-text"> 
   Random text random text random text random text random text random text
   </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-caption {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
 }
```

Comment: `rgba` is the way to ge here. Why are you avoiding it?

Comment: I'm a new to programing. And I'm constantly finding out that all the things I'm doing can be achieved much easier, so i thought that i can avoid rgba too :) seems I'll have to stick with it...

Comment: You could also use a semitransparent bg image, or there is an absolute positioning hack that would allow you to use opacity, but it's not worth it in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)`, as you pointed. `opacity` is not only background opacity. It changes text opacity also.
Or you can use

```
background-color:#00000033
```